# Quality of life improved in Monster hunter XX

Tags: nintendo-switch, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl, monster-hunter-generations-ultimate

Is Monster hunter XX on Switch a direct port of the 3ds version (with better graphics) or has also better quality of life features such as faster gathering of resources, better crafting, documentation on screen and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monster Hunter Double Cross (aka XX) is pretty much a direct port with updated graphics from the 3DS version but content and gameplaywise it is identical. This also makes it able to crossplay between Switch and 3DS versions in online rooms but not local play.

Note, the crossplay feature is only available in the japanese XX versions for 3DS and Switch since the international release of XX titled Monster Hunter Generations Ultimate was only released for the Switch.